# django Multiple form submit in UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I want to update the built-in User model along with the Profile (user extended) model.

this is ***forms.py***:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = auth_models.User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['date_of_birth']
```

this is my ***view.py***:

```
class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView, MultiModelForm):
    model = Profile
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.request.user
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username__iexact=username)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('accounts:profile')
```

This just edits Profile fields.

I also tested [django-betterforms](https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but couldn't make it work. I could show 2 forms with get_context_data() but I couldn't save to model and that was just HTML.

I just want to know how get_object for the second form?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but `username = self.request.user` is semantically wrong as it is the `User` object not its `username`. You might use `username = self.request.user.username` or simply change your query to `return get_object_or_404(Profile, user=self.request.user)`

Comment: Thanks, but the question is something else. multiple forms in this view.

Comment: The generic `UpdateView` isn't supposed to work with multiple models. It's also not that easy to change it to work fo multiple objects. You're better off using a function view that does everything. Or, if you are going to reuse the code and really want to create a CBV for this, you could copy the code of `UpdateView` and replace it to work for multiple models/forms. Instead of `get_form` you'd have `get_forms` and for `get_object` you'd have `get_objects`, all returning dictionaries.

Comment: Maybe using `MultiModelForm` from django-betterforms isn't a bad idea, the example shown in the documentation is almost exactly what you want. You only need one object (if `Profile` has a foreign key to `User`) and need to override the `get_form_kwargs()` and `form_valid()` methods of your `UpdateView`.

Comment: Yes, I could make django-betterforms work. Thanks.